# How to open <visualStudioProject>.sln TXT file in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, project

I made a small application in C# in visual studio 2012 in my laptop. I made a zip of the complete project and copied the zipped folder to another system. I unzipped the project and found out the project files are showing as TXT file. I tried opening them using visual studio 2012 but it didnt opened. Following is the screenshot of the the directory:

[image]

[image]

Why it is showing .sln as TXT file and all the form.cs as TXT file. How to open this is in visual studio 2012.?

Comment: `Right Click => Open with => Choose Program => Visual Studio`. Or From VS, `File => Open => Project / Solution => Browse to the .sln file`.

Comment: @when I browse to the .sln file, in the file dialog box, it doesnt show any files

Comment: Is the `.sln` file in that folder ?

Comment: Yes its in the same folder inside the project directory

Comment: Have you tried the first approach ? To right click the `.sln` file and .... (steps above)

Comment: I tried the first approach. right clicking the .sln file and open with visual studio shows some txt data. not the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.

It was showing their extension as txt file. For example `form1.cs.txt` So I renamed it and changed to `form1.cs` and did the same for every file in the project. Now its working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file, choose properties option,  change the open with property to Microsoft Visual Studio. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project, choose unload. Double click to open as txt. After edit Right click on project, choose load.

Comment: Where this unload option comes.? Inside the project or in the directory.?

Comment: In `visual studio`, In `Solution Explorer`, right-click the project and select `Unload Project`.